# In dictionary, converting the value from string to integer

Tags: python, string, dictionary, integer

Taking this below example :

```
'user_stats': {'Blog': '1',
                'Discussions': '2',
                'Followers': '21',
                'Following': '21',
                'Reading': '5'},
```

I want to convert it into:

```
'Blog' : 1 , 'Discussion': 2, 'Followers': 21, 'Following': 21, 'Reading': 5
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
dict_with_ints = dict((k,int(v)) for k,v in dict_with_strs.iteritems())
```

Comment: Note that [`iteritems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) [is gone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems) in [Python 3](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/). Use [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) instead.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
{k:int(v) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

where `d` is the dictionary with the strings.

Comment: @IvanVirabyan You can also use dictionary comprehensions in python 2.7 since they have been backported.

Comment: In fact, that code will only work in Python 2.7 . `dict.iteritems` is gone in 3, since `dict.items` no longer builds a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> d = {'Blog': '1', 'Discussions': '2', 'Followers': '21', 'Following': '21', 'Reading': '5'}
>>> dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())
{'Blog': 1, 'Discussions': 2, 'Followers': 21, 'Following': 21, 'Reading': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lest anyone be mislead by this page - Dictionary literals in Python 2 and 3 can of course have numeric values directly.

```
embed={ 'the':1, 'cat':42, 'sat':2, 'on':32, 'mat':200, '.':4 }
print(embed['cat']) # 42
```